# Maven dependencies error

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I'm new with Maven and I'm stuck with dependencies.

I'm trying to create my own executable jar with all its dependencies.

I can achieve this in Eclipse exporting my project and obtaining a jar file with inside the necessary jars (I try to execute it and it runs).

I have tried to write my own `pom.xml` but I encountered some problems.

My dependencies are (`commons-lang`, `log4j` and `terrier`)

I have added these line:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.terrier</groupId>
  <artifactId>terrier</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get the following error after call `mvn clean package`

UPDATE logs for `mvn clean package -e`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project terrier-cw: Could not resolve dependencies for project uk.ac.ucl:terrier-cw:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:     Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project terrier-cw: Could not resolve dependencies for project uk.ac.ucl:terrier-cw:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project uk.ac.ucl:terrier-cw:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
... 23 more
 Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.terrier:terrier:jar:4.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
... 27 more
```

Comment: should the artifactId be `terrier` or `terrier-core` ?

Comment: run this command and post the logs `mvn clean package -e`

Comment: i've edited my question

Comment: and nothing change.. same for terrier or terrier-core

Comment: @Big Poppa there doesnt exist `terrier artifacts` in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2? where do you  get `terrier artifacts`? Do you build a `terrier artifacts` yourself?

Comment: I don't know how i can build terrier artifact by myself.. have you got any suggestion?

Comment: Did you clean install `terrier`?

Comment: i want a jar that also another person can run without having to install terrier in its machine..

Comment: The given depdendency `org.terrier` does not exist in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|org.terrier) so neither Maven can't find it...